# Passing $$ as command line variable

Tags: unix, command-line

When I pass `$$` as command line variable then it returns garbage numbers during `echo ?`

For example, while running my script I type -

```
sh testscript.sh 1 $$STRT_DT
```

Inside the script when I `print $2` - `echo $2`, then the value returned is `6504STRT_DT`.
Please advise.

I want to pass the entire string "$$STRT_DT" as `$2`

Comment: $ is a scpecial character for variables in the shell. Use quotes around it.

Answer (score 3):

`$$` is a built-in shell variable that contains the process ID of the shell. If you want to pass it literally, you need to escape or quote it:

```
sh testscript.sh 1 '$$STRT_DT'
```

Comment: Thank you .. This helped .. Now I feel so stuping having asked such a basic thing :)

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please consider accepting it. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

`$$` the process ID of the current shell. It's not clear what you are *trying* to do with `$$STRT_DT`.